# Python scatter plot colors based on values

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to create a map that plots the intensity of wind speed from satellite data. The data consists of longitude, latitude, and the wind speed intensity. The longitude/latitude plots the locations (done), while the speed gives each point a color based on the value of the wind data.

As of now, all points are colored blue (look at script).

The data frame looks like this:

```
    lon    lat   wind_speed
1   13.0   75.3  23.5
2   12.9   25.2  23.7
3   12.7   75.2  24.2
4   12.6   75.1  24.6
           ...
```

The result should look something like this:
https://gyazo.com/118d4785b49c861096f93799f60a0622

here is my current code:

```
import os
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

... #ncdump, this is from a file in my computer


#variables for map in array form
wind_speed_array =nc_fid.variables['wind_speed_alt']
lats=nc_fid.variables['lat'][:]
lons =nc_fid.variables['lon'][:]


fig = plt.figure()
fig.autofmt_xdate()
m = Basemap(projection='mill',resolution='l')
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries()
plt.title("time series plot: wind speed")

x,y=m(lons,lats)
cs=m.scatter(x,y,wind_speed_array,color='blue')

plt.show()
```

Currently, I have a map with all the points, but they are all colored blue. How would I make the points colored based on their value like in the example picture?

Comment: Have you tried to use `seaborn`'s `scatterplot` and pass the values to `hue` argument? I think it would be easier that way.

Comment: The command would be `m.scatter(x, y, c=wind_speed_array)`.

Comment: I replaced the command with cs=m.scatter(x,y,c=wind_speed_array). However, I got an error that, 'c' argument has 11130 elements, which is not acceptable for use with 'x' with size 5565, 'y' with size '5565'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have colormap as your input argument `color` and I think [LinearColorMap](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap) should work nicely.

A [`colorbar`](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/colorbar_placement.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-colorbar-placement-py) will help you get the *legend bar* like the one at the bottom of your example.